# jQuery: is there a way to .LOAD() content that has script references in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 files. One called foo1.php and the other called foo2.php.

**Contents of foo1.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yoxview/yoxview-init.js"></script>

<div class="yoxview">
<a href="files/Desert.jpg"><img src="files/Desert.jpg" alt="First" title="First image" /></a>
<a href="files/Hydrangeas.jpg"><img src="files/hydrangeas.jpg" alt="Second" title="Second image" /></a>
<a href="files/Jellyfish.jpg"><img src="files/Jellyfish.jpg" alt="Third" title="Third image" /></a>
</div>
```

**Contents of foo2.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.bar').load('foo1.php');

});

</script>

<div class="bar">this text will be replaced</div>
```

When I go to foo2.php I get a blank white page with a never ending loading favicon. I think this has something to do with loading the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yoxview/yoxview-init.js"></script>
```

in foo1.php since the contents of that page are passed through the .load() function. When I remove that script reference foo1.php loads just fine. I don't think this problem is specific to that particular script. If I try to load any page with a script reference the same result occurs (the blank page/loading favicon).

Is there a way to load content from another page that has script references?

### EDIT

Here's the link to the problem script:

http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/yoxview/yoxview-init.js

Comment: When you load content using `.load()`, any script references will be parsed and executed. The problem must be with the script reference (it is being loaded and seems to hang). It's impossible for us to tell what is wrong with it without seeing its code

Comment: @Unicron think you're right, here's a link to the code: http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/yoxview/yoxview-init.js

Comment: the problem must be in there, but I'm not sure where exactly. It does a number of things that could somehow end up in an endless loop

Comment: @unicron yeah I'm pretty sure its the document.write, when I remove it the page loads fine. Just have to figure out what the var url means so I can write that script reference in the html manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to intercept the document.write, it's worked for me in the past: https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture